# From FCC- How to return the lowest index of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

This is my first post, so excuse me if I am not following a certain pattern!
I am new to coding and working on the JS problems from freecodecamp on this section problem (javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-algorithm-scripting/where-do-i-belong).

When I pass this one argument getIndexToIns([2, 5, 10], 15), it doesn't give me the return value of 3.
I understand because this doesn't pass my condition if( num <= sortedArr[i]){return i;}, but I don't seem to get any way how to solve this.

Following the same code below, would anyone be able to provide me an answer so I can get the result?

Thanks a lot in advance, Niki

**Problem: Return the lowest index at which a value (second argument) should be inserted into an array (first argument) once it has been sorted. The returned value should be a number.**

**Code:**

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) 
{
  if(arr.length === 0)
  {
    return 0;
  }

    let sortedArr = arr.sort(function(a,b)
    {
      return a - b
    });
 
  for (i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i ++)
  {

    if( num <= sortedArr[i])
    {
      return i;
    }
  }
}

getIndexToIns([2, 5, 10], 15)
```

Comment: You're right, if the value is larger than all the elements in the array then your condition is never met and your return never fires. You'll need a default return value after your loop to account for this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yeah, that worked! @pilchard

Comment: Suggestion: Sorting your list makes it ```O(NlogN)```. A simple linear traversal would give a faster ```O(N)``` algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Key thing to keep in mind is that is you don't find a num <= some value in the array, your code won't return anything. The number 15 is greater than any value in the array, so the for loop isn't finding anything. One option is to return the full array length if an index isn't found, since then you know that the new num will be added at the end.

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  const sortedArr = arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });
 
  for (let i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i++) {
    if( num <= sortedArr[i]) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return arr.length;
}

const idx = getIndexToIns([2, 5, 10], 15);
console.log(idx)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This code made sense. I wish I could have thought that too :)  @Isaac B

Comment: Happy to help. When you're lost, it's good to console.log your results, as well as anything else that may be useful, to see whether your code is doing what you think it is. In this case you would notice that your function was returning `undefined` instead of a number. This is always a clue that your function isn't actually returning anything.

Comment: Yeah got it! :) Thanks again!